# Leap year program in C

Tags: c

I am just starting to code in C and as a part of a tutorial assignment, I was given to write a program to take input and check if it's a leap year or not. Very basic.
I pretty much wrote the code and ran it but during debugging I realized my 'year' variable was storing some garbage value. I searched on the web quite extensively and found out that my code is not wrong. But I'm surely wrong as I'm getting garbage values but not able to find out where I made a mistake. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(){
    int year;
    printf("Enter any year \n");
    scanf("%d", &year); //take input
    printf("%d", &year);    //just to debug
     if((year%4==0) && ((year%100!=0)||(year%400==0)))  //check the input for leap year
        printf("\nIt's a Leap Year");
    else
        printf("\nIt's not a Leap Year");
}
```

I am using VSCode as my IDE.

The sample output is

```
Enter any year
2016
767555836
It's a Leap Year
```

Please help me figure out what I am missing here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `printf("%d", &year);` -> `printf("%d", year);`.

Comment: `printf("%d\n", year);` unless you want the address of the variable, then `printf("%p\n", (void*)&year);`

Comment: You're printing the address of the `year` variable. Try printing `year` instead of `&year`

Comment: Unrelated: whatever is in `<conio.h>` you're not using, so remove that `#include`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your compiler should show some warning about this obvious error. It should warn about mismatch of expected type for `%d` format specifier and provided parameter of type `int*`. If it doesn't turn up warning level.

Comment: Unrelated: `void main()` is not 100% legal: prefer `int main(void)`

Comment: The fact that you are including `conio.h` and the invalid return type for `main` makes me wonder what compiler you are using and what tutorial you might be taking.

Comment: @Gerhardh And how even VSCODE working with those ancient compilers

Comment: To make SO work properly, you are supposed to give feedback to comments and answers.

Comment: thank you @L.Scott Johnsson
appreciate the help

Comment: No need to thank everyone. Giving a +1 normally is sufficient. Besides accepting an answer if it solves the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printf specifier '%d' take the value of the variable. not the address of variable.when you use & before the name of the variable its mean the address of variable. but you want to print the value of the variable. so dont use &.

```
printf("%d", year);
```

it should work now.